# How do I say ‘I like to go out in such nice weather’ in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say ‘I like to go out in such nice weather’ in Spanish?

> *Me gustaria salir en un tal buen tiempo.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One different (and more common way in Spain IMHO) way to say it:

> Me gusta salir con tan buen tiempo

Or even:

> Me gusta salir cuando hace un tiempo tan bueno

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is a good first try, but it has several inaccuracies:

> Me gustaria salir en un tal buen tiempo.

1. **Me gustaría** is *I would like*.  The *-ia* ending is used in the Spanish [conditional tense](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/conditional.htm).  But in your sentence, you simply want to say "I like", so **Me gusta** is what you want.
2. **un .. tiempo**

   We don't talk about "A weather" in Spanish (or in English, for that matter).  By including the word *un*, it makes it appear (at least to me), that you're talking about *a good time* (*tiempo* can mean both *time* and *weather* in Spanish).  So get rid of **un**.
3. **tal buen tiempo**

   I don't believe I have ever confused *tal* and *tan*, but it seems to be a common confusion.  But in your case, you definitely want **tan**. You can read about [*tal*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tal) and [*tan*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tan), or feel free to ask another question to dig into the differences in more detail.

So after these adjustments, the correct translation for your phrase would be (changes highlighted):

> Me gusta<strike>ria</strike> salir en <strike>un</strike> **tan** buen tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Me gusta salir en un clima tan bueno como este.

Me gusta salir en un clima así de bueno.

Me gusta salir con tan buen tiempo/clima

Comment: I thought 'such' was translated as 'tal'?

Comment: Such can also be translated as tan, depending of the context. The third one has the closest structure to your original English sentence.

Comment: As a comment: What you put as translation is a LITERAL word by word translation, it is LITERALLY correct, but both languages don't have the same structures so it doesn't really sound right. And gustaría = I'd like

Comment: You can see I put 'depending of the context' in my first comment. That is the type of mistake you just made. It should have been 'depending on the context' but I used a Spanish structure, which to me sounds right but to you it may sound weird and non-correct. Good luck.